# Sending packets from separate application to Ryu

Tags: sockets, sdn, openflow, pox, ryu

I am trying to send data from a Northbound application that I have written, into the Ryu application.
The NB app is performing a lot of computation, so I have chosen to run it outside of Ryu. How do I send this information into the Ryu controller so the controller can act on it.

This set up would look like this:

[Northbound packet sender with actionable information (not in the SDN dataplane!!)]

↓

[Ethernet 1 (if on a different machine), or the Linux localhost (if on the same machine)]

↓

[Ryu Machine]

↓

[Ethernet 2 (using OpenFlow)]

↓

[Data plane]

In Pox I have simply set up a thread that can receive packets on a port. When it receives a packet it just creates an event, and my main SDN app can then use this event to perform the network changes needed. When I try this approach in Ryu, it just doesn't work. It seems that when I try to register a socket inside a Ryu app, Ryu will not run until that functionality has been removed.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Run the socket in a separate thread.
Run socket server on Ryu PC instead of client.